# Is this a PHP bug ("false" == 0)?

Tags: php

```
if ("false" == 0) echo "true\n";
// => true
```

While PHP documentation says:

```
var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)
```

If it is a bug where can I file it?

Comment: `false` is a boolean false. `'false'` and `"false"` are strings which happen to contain the word false. non-empty strings evaluate to a boolean true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, not a bug. Don't bother filing it.

This seemingly inconsistent behavior has nothing to do with the word "false". It has to do with your string consisting of only letters and no numeric digits, so when it gets cast to an integer for comparison (`== 0`), it results in 0, making `0 == 0` which evaluates to true.

If you compare any other alphabetic string to 0, you'll get the same result:

```
"abcd" == 0
"a" == 0
"true" == 0
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not a bug, it's a well documented feature when comparing values of different datatypes - in this case, string to integer. PHP converts the string to an integer to do the comparison, and "false" converts to 0.

See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.

and this page on [string to number conversion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

> If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

To avoid this behaviour, use comparison with strict typing:

```
if ("false" === 0) echo "true\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that PHP casts variables unless you use a strict comparison. As others mentioned, the string `"false"` is being cast to an integer.

If you want to do a comparison without typecasting use:

```
"false" === 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help: These are the only things that PHP considers false:

Actual boolean false

NULL values (empty)

The Integer 0

Try to avoid string comparisons of text and stick with booleans!